# How to plot time on the X-axis in non-ugly mode?

Tags: nvd3.js

This **is ugly**:

[image]

I need something that is not ugly. Time series are very usual, but I not see how to build a "plug and play" chart with ISO dates.

Perhaps an equivalent question is *"How to use [d3-scalelinear/Non-numeric range/Date](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scalelinear) with NVD3?"* 
(or [d3-scaletime](https://observablehq.com/@d3/d3-scaletime))

---

### Notes

This is the main code:

```js
    nv.addGraph(function () {

        var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
          //.x( d=> d.label )  // very Ugly!
          .x( d=> { 
                let dd = new Date(d.label); 
                return d3.time.format('%b %d')(dd)  
           })  // Ugly, because need to jump some days before show next
          .y( d=> d.value )
          .staggerLabels(true) // not solved

        d3.select('#chart svg')
          .datum(data)
          .transition().duration(500)
          .call(chart);

        nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update); // necessary?

        return chart;
    }); // \nv.add
```

I try some variations, no one work fine (all ugly).

My data is something as

```
    [ {  
      key: "ExampleData",
      color: "#ff7f0e",  
      values: [
         { label: "2019-03-28", value: 7.8389242307 },
         { label: "2019-03-29", value: 9.4185632435 },
         { label: "2019-03-30", value: 7.3553138346 },
         { label: "...", value: ... }
      ]
    } ];
```

​​
The values Array have ~100 items.

---

### Problematic workarounds

This (not elegant) solution loss the *tooltip*, as illustrated,

[image]

```
var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart()
   .x( d=> d.label )
   .y( d=> d.value )
   .staggerLabels(true);
chart.xAxis
  .showMaxMin(false)
  .tickFormat(function(d) {
    let dd =  new Date(d)
    return (dd.getDay()==1)? d3.time.format('%x')(aux): '';
  });  // each 7 days format, else empty string
```

---

This other solution, http://jsfiddle.net/ee2todev/3Lu46oqg/
seems good and elegant, using `d3.scale.ordinal().domain(valuesForXAxis).rangePoints([0,width])`, but is not NVD3, is pure D3...

---

The [NVD3 Live `Line Plus Bar Chart`](http://nvd3.org/livecode/index.html#codemirrorNav) seems good (!), but the input data is not ISO date, is something very strange (unix time?) that is a ordinal domain and is automatically displayed with non-ugly algorithm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using historicalBarChart which can have time series on x axis.

```
  var chart = nv.models.historicalBarChart()
   .x(function(d) { return d[0]})
   .y(function(d) { return d[1]})
   .useInteractiveGuideline(true);

  ...

  chart.xAxis
    .showMaxMin(false)
    .tickFormat(function(d) {
      return d3.time.format('%x')(new Date(d))
    });
```

Working example is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ovvn/u8shcvnf/16/).